# JS/(X) import: to import React components?

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch

I want to import a React component from a jsx file in a template and render it in the template with `ReactDOM`. Later in production I would only want to ship react and all the dependencies of the component only when a site is loaded that has that component.

I have created a React component like this:
`editor.jsx`

```
import * as React from "react";
import {Editor} from "draft-js-plugins-editor";
const plugins = [];

export class EditorComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props);
this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
};
}
onChange(editorState)  {
this.setState({
        editorState,
    });
}
render() {
return (<Editor
editorState={this.state.editorState}
onChange={this.onChange}
plugins={plugins}
/>);
}
}
```

http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets suggests the require syntax for accessing module exports. So I added the following to my template `<script>const editor = require("web/static/js/editor").EditorComponent</script>`. This does not work though, because the browser cannot interpret require (or brunch does not pick it up).

I configured brunch like so:

```
plugins: {
babel: {
// Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
   ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/],
    presets: ["es2015","react"]
}
},
modules: {
autoRequire: {
"js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"],
"js/editor.jsx": ["web/static/js/editor"]
}
},
```

I am a bit lost here. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

One idea that pops to mind is to create a JS file and import it in the template you want with a `<script>` tag. In the same template create an empty `<div id=editor>`. Then, in the JS file import React and ReactDOM and the component you want and use something like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Editor/>,
   document.getElementById("editor")
)
```

However, I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly.